# pandas groupby and apply function on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

If I have a function `f` that I am applying to more than once to a set of columns, what's a more Pythonic way of going about it. Right now, what I am doing is this.

```
newdf=df.groupby(['a', 'b']).apply(lambda x: f(x, 1))
newdf.columns=['1']
newdf['2']=df.groupby(['a', 'b']).apply(lambda x: f(x, 2))
newdf['3']=df.groupby(['a', 'b']).apply(lambda x: f(x, 3))
newdf['4']=df.groupby(['a', 'b']).apply(lambda x: f(x, 4))
```

Is there a better way of going about it?

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe and expected output.

Comment: I deleted my answer too since I don't think it was pythonic enough, and pandas groupby can be tricky. I'll leave it here and say you can *try* `newdf = pd.concat(
    df.groupby(['a', 'b']).apply(lambda x: f(x, i)) for i in range(1, 5), axis=1
)`. And a sample dataframe would help.

Comment: @Linda Can you tell us what the function is doing?

Comment: I agree with others, if you can share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be easy to help you. Depending on the function you can even get rid of the `apply`

Answer (score 2):

That's pythonic enough for me:

```
columns_dict = dict()
for i in range(1, 5):
    columns_dict[str(i)] = df.groupby(["a", "b"]).apply(lambda x: f(x, i))

pd.DataFrame(columns_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do :

```
pandas.DataFrame([df.groupby(['a','b']).apply(lambda x : f(x,i)) for i in range(1,5)])
```

Then transpose the new DataFrame if you want to have same column names as the initial dataframe.

Comment: This is not significantly different by Jay Calamari's answer.

Comment: The Jay Calamari's soltution won't even work, as the `pandas.concat function needs arguments to be passed as a list. He is missing some brackets over there !

Answer (score 0):

Use [`agg()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to compute multiple values from a single `groupby()`:

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b']).agg([
    ('1': lambda x: f(x, 1)),
    ('2': lambda x: f(x, 2)),
    ('3': lambda x: f(x, 3)),
    ('4': lambda x: f(x, 4)),
])
```

Or equivalently:

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b']).agg([(str(i), lambda x: f(x, i)) for i in range(1, 5)])
```

Comment: Does this work for `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5], 'b':[3]})`  and `def f(x,i): return x**i` ?

Comment: @astro123: I don't know, does it?  Do I look like a Python interpreter?

Comment: obviously not. :)   I was practicing that pandas example, did not work, and was wondering why it didn't work?

Comment: unfortunately .agg does not support the index through x.name

Answer (score 0):

Pandas [`groupby.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) accepts arbitrary arguments and keyword arguments, which are passed on to the grouping function. In addition, you can create a dictionary mapping column to argument. Finally, you can also reuse a `groupby` object, which can be defined outside your loop.

```
argmap = {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4}

grouper = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])

for k, v in argmap.items():
    newdf[k] = grouper.apply(f, v)
```

Comment: I think he wants multiple arguments to be passed to the apply function, rather than calling the apply function multiple times.. this is important when the two columns are required in a single invocation